# Non-Root elements in Finite Groups

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group. I'm interested in understanding the elements $g$ which don't have any non-trivial roots in G in the sense that if $h^n = g$ for some $h$ in $G$ and positive integer $n$, then $(n, |g|) = 1$. Definition can be made similarly using Frobenius-Schur indicators:
$\theta_n(g) = 1$ if $(n,|g|) = 1$ and $0$ otherwise.

Let $Z$ be the set of such non-root elements in $G$. $Z_p$ can be similarly defined for p-elements where $p \mid  |G|$.  There are several topics that I would like to explore such as:

(1) the interplay between the characteristics $Z$, $Z_p$ and the order, exponent, subgroup structure of $G$.

(2) character values of elements in $ Z$ or $Z_p$ for irreducible Complex / Brauer characters of $G$.

Can someone point me to the existing research on these topics? I did some google but haven't found anything relevant. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using dollar signs starts math mode in MSE posts, just as in latex.. I have changed it for you but you should use them if u ask more questions

Comment: Thank you for letting me know.